# How to check for the word logo in URLs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, image, capture-group

I want to select logo image urls from a HTML string. I assume that the logo image URL will have text 'logo' somewhere in it's URL.

Need a regex that selects Image URLs from a given HTML string text. The logo URL will have text 'logo' in it's path.

```
/(https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?[\w+-_.0-9@\/]+logo.(?:png|jpg|jpeg))/i
```

```
["https://static.infragistics.com/marketing/Website/home/espn-logo.png", "https://static.infragistics.com/marketing/Website/home/mondelez-logo.png", "https://static.infragistics.com/marketing/Website/home/nielsen-logo.png", "https://static.infragistics.com/marketing/Website/home/united-logo.png", "https://static.infragistics.com/marketing/Website/home/merrill-lynch-logo.png", "https://static.infragistics.com/marketing/Website/home/dell-logo.png", "https://static.infragistics.com/marketing/Website/home/intel-logo.png", "https://static.infragistics.com/marketing/Website/home/prudential-logo.png", "https://static.infragistics.com/marketing/Website/home/mcdonalds-logo.png"]
```

The text logo can present anywhere in the URL.

Need a regex that picks Image URls which has text 'logo' in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe, it would be a good idea to reduce our constraints in the expression, maybe without even word boundaries for `logo`, with some expression similar to:

```
(?i)^(?=.*logo)(?:https)?:\/\/\S+(?:png|jpe?g|gif|tiff)$
```

where,

```
(?=.*logo)
```

would simply check if there is a `logo` anywhere in the URL.

---

If we would just want to check the word `logo`, in the image names,

```
espn-logo.png
espn-logos.png
```

we would move our positive lookahead forward, after the last slash, for instance:

```
(?i)^(?:https)?:\/\/\S+\/(?=.*logo).*(?:png|jpe?g|gif|tiff)$
```

and our [desired image extensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_file_formats) would go in this non-capturing group:

```
(?:png|jpe?g|gif|tiff|svg)
```

#### Test

```
re = /(?i)^(?=.*logo)(?:https)?:\/\/\S+(?:png|jpe?g|gif|tiff)$/s
str = 'https://static.infragistics.com/marketing/Website/home/espn-logo.png
https://static.infragistics.com/marketing/Website/home/mondelez-logo.gif
https://static.infragistics.com/marketing/Website/home/nielsen-logo.jpg
https://static.infragistics.com/marketing/Website/home/united-logo.jpeg
https://static.infragistics.com/marketing/Website/home/merrill-lynch-logo.PNG
https://static.infragistics.com/marketing/Website/home/dell-logo.TIFF
https://static.infragistics.com/marketing/Website/home/intel-logo.gif
https://static.infragistics.com/marketing/Website/home/prudential-logo.png
https://static.infragistics.com/marketing/Website/home/mcdonalds-logo.GIF
https://static.infragistics.com/marketing/Website/home/mcdonalds-alogo.GIF
https://static.infragistics.com/marketing/Website/home/mcdonalds-logos.GIF'

str.scan(re) do |match|
    puts match.to_s
end
```

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/myzdJy/1/), if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it, and in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/myzdJy/1/debugger), you can watch how it would match against some sample inputs, if you like.

---

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

#### Edit

For those cases that we have other instances of URLs, we would usually add more constraints for the edge cases, such as:

```
(?i)(?<=")\s*(?:https?)?:\/\/[^"]+\/(?=[^"]*logo)[^"]*(?:png|jpe?g|gif|tiff)\s*(?=")
```

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/R7tVfU/1/)

---

I guess maybe it would be easier to first collect the image URLs, then we would check if there is a `\blogo\b` in the image names. Otherwise, the expression might get complicated.

Comment: Love your answers. @Emma

Comment: Can you please take a look at https://rubular.com/r/5HO4sD3vKYDJ3i
Select urls which are image URLs and have logo text in it's URL.

Comment: You are God level. Thank you so much!! @Emma